# How to refactor similar and repetitive functions in scala

Tags: scala, refactoring, dry

I have this kind of code at multiple places in my project:

```
def fun1(paramA: A, url: String)(implicit x: X): Future[T] = {
  val select = x.someFunction(url)
  val res = anotherFunction(select, paramA).mapTo[T]
  res
}

def fun2(paramB: B, url: String)(implicit x: X): Future[T] = {
  val select = x.someFunction(url)
  val res = anotherFunction(select, paramB).mapTo[T]
  res
}

def fun3(paramC: C, url: String)(implicit x: X): Future[T] = {
  val select = x.someFunction(url)
  val res = anotherFunction(select, paramC).mapTo[T]
  res
}
```

I feel it is not following DRY. Also whenever I need to change something I have to update the code on all methods.

I recently started coding in Scala, previously I was working with Ruby which is not typed language. I am not sure this is the best/correct way of writing in Scala or we can refactor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided any relevant information on types `X` or `T`, but from your example code it looks like you could do something like this.

```
def fun[P](param: P, url: String)(implicit x: X): Future[T] =
  anotherFunction(x.someFunction(url), param).mapTo[T]
```

This assumes that `someFunction()` is the same function in all three examples. (Likewise for `anotherFunction()`.)